# Cannot turn on overlay plane using OpenGL in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, visual-studio-2017, qt5

We are porting some C++ code from Visual Studio 2008/Qt4 to Visual Studio 2017/Qt5 and cannot turn on the overlay plane using OpenGL 4.5 with a NVIDIA Quadro graphics card. The same code is okay in VS2008/Qt4. Following is a small sample program.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf ("debug test1\n");
    QApplication a (argc, argv);

    QGLFormat glFmt;
    glFmt.setStereo (true);
    glFmt.setOverlay (true); 
    glFmt.setDoubleBuffer (true);

    QGLWidget *qtWid = new QGLWidget (glFmt);
    qtWid->show();
    printf ("version           %d.%d\n", qtWid->format().majorVersion(), qtWid->format().minorVersion());
    printf ("stereo            %d\n",    qtWid->format().stereo());
    printf ("hasOverlay        %d\n",    qtWid->format().hasOverlay());
    printf ("hasOpenGLOverlays %d\n",    qtWid->format().hasOpenGLOverlays());
    printf ("doubleBuffer      %d\n",    qtWid->format().doubleBuffer());

    return a.exec ();
}
```

In VS2017/Qt5, hasOverlay and hasOpenGLOverlays always return 0. In VS2008/Qt4 they return 1. The Quadro card has a hardware overlay plane and it is turned on in the NVIDIA Control Panel.

Did OpenGL in QT5 stop supporting the hardware overlay plane?

Comment: Using `QOpenGLWidget` in Qt 5 and see this
https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/a37dd93defd91b79fb6730d0ff0515a66a0d3972/src/opengl/qgl.cpp#L1256

Comment: Thank you for the information, Jiu. Do you know how to turn on and(or) check the overlay plane in QOpenGLWidget?